# How can I memorize a sparse banded matrix with scipy.sparse.dia_matrix giving it arrays (diagonals) of different dimensions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy

I want to memorize a pentadiagonal square matrix with `scipy.sparse.dia_matrix`. The first and the last diagonal are far away from the main diagonal, so they contain fewer elements than the main diagonal. It seems `dia_matrix` accepts only diagonal of the same length of the main diagonal. I want to save memory and give it an array of different length. Is it possible? Below an example (tridiagonal):

```
diag1 = [88,99]
main_diag = [1,2,3,4]
diag2 = [ 101,202]



A = [ 1,   0, 88, 0
      0,   2,  0, 99
      101, 0,  3, 0
      0,  202, 0, 4 ] 
A = scipy.sparse.dia_matrix(([[diag1],[main_diag],[diag2]],offsets), shape= (4,4))
```

But it give me an error unless I don't memorize diagonals as:

```
diag1 = [0,0,88,99]
main_diag = [1,2,3,4]
diag2 = [ 101,202,0,0]
```

But in this way it is not memory saving.

Answer (score 0):

Your dense matrix (why didn't you make this cut-n-paste compatible?):

```
In [589]: A = np.array([[ 1,   0, 88, 0],
     ...:       [0,   2,  0, 99],
     ...:       [101, 0,  3, 0],
     ...:       [0,  202, 0, 4] ])
     ...:       
In [590]: A
Out[590]: 
array([[  1,   0,  88,   0],
       [  0,   2,   0,  99],
       [101,   0,   3,   0],
       [  0, 202,   0,   4]])
```

We can make the `dia` matrix directly from `A`:

```
In [591]: M = sparse.dia_matrix(A)
In [592]: M
Out[592]: 
<4x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 8 stored elements (3 diagonals) in DIAgonal format>
```

`dia` format stores is values in two arrays, a 2d `data` and 1d `offsets`:

```
In [593]: M.data
Out[593]: 
array([[101, 202,   0,   0],
       [  1,   2,   3,   4],
       [  0,   0,  88,  99]])
In [594]: M.offsets
Out[594]: array([-2,  0,  2], dtype=int32)
```

We can use the `sparse.diags` function to construct the `dia` matrix from your 3 diagonals:

```
In [605]: M1 = sparse.diags([diag1, main_diag, diag2],[2,0,-2], dtype=int)
In [606]: M1
Out[606]: 
<4x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 8 stored elements (3 diagonals) in DIAgonal format>
In [607]: M1.A
Out[607]: 
array([[  1,   0,  88,   0],
       [  0,   2,   0,  99],
       [101,   0,   3,   0],
       [  0, 202,   0,   4]])
In [608]: M1.data
Out[608]: 
array([[  0,   0,  88,  99],
       [  1,   2,   3,   4],
       [101, 202,   0,   0]])
```

But the underlying storage is the same.

I don't know the details of why `dia_matrix` uses this format.  I suspect it has to do with balance of storage and processing costs.  To store the `data` as a 2d array it has to have some sort of padding.  Otherwise you have use a list of lists (or object array of arrays/lists) as in `[diag1, main_diag, diag2]`.  Whether that uses more or less memory may depend on the size of the matrix and how far out the `offsets` are.

In `lil` format the same matrix is stored as 2 arrays of lists:

```
In [611]: M.tolil().data
Out[611]: 
array([list([1, 88]), list([2, 99]), list([101, 3]), list([202, 4])],
      dtype=object)
In [612]: M.tolil().rows
Out[612]: 
array([list([0, 2]), list([1, 3]), list([0, 2]), list([1, 3])],
      dtype=object)
```

and in `coo`:

```
In [615]: M.tocoo().data
Out[615]: array([101, 202,   1,   2,   3,   4,  88,  99])
In [616]: M.tocoo().row
Out[616]: array([2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1], dtype=int32)
In [617]: M.tocoo().col
Out[617]: array([0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3], dtype=int32)
```

`csr`, which is widely used for calculations, compresses the `row` array.

If you are doing all the calculations in the dense form, you might want to construct `A` from something like:

```
np.diag(main_diag,0)+np.diag(diag1,2)+np.diag(diag2,-2)
```

Comparing this with the `sparse` mediated approach:

```
In [623]: timeit np.diag(main_diag,0)+np.diag(diag1,2)+np.diag(diag2,-2)
27.5 µs ± 1.28 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [624]: timeit sparse.diags([diag1, main_diag, diag2],[2,0,-2], dtype=int).A
288 µs ± 13 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: I see that in this way I'm not saving memory because M1.data contains 4+4+4 elemenst, not 2+4+2 elements as I want. I want to optimize memory.

Comment: But when you compare lists of list with 2d arrays, you can't just count elements.  You could save `np.hstack([diag1, main_diag, diag2])`, and then, based on shape and offsets, split that into the 3 subarrays.